# Counting the rows if certain criteria is fullfiled and entering result to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i have the following code for calculating the avarage value of cells if certain criteria is fulfilled.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages

     Const YEAR = 2019

    ' open source workbook
    Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

    If Len(fname) = 0 Then
       MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
       Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table 2") '

    ' scan down source workbook calc average
    Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sMth As String, iMth As Long
    Dim count(12) As Long, sum(12) As Long

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow

        If IsDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) _
            And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then

            iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))   ' col H
            sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30) ' Col AD
            count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1 '

        End If
    Next

    ' close source worbook no save
    wbSource.Close False

    ' update Table 2 with averages
    With ws.Range("A3")
    For iMth = 1 To 12
        .Offset(0, iMth - 1) = MonthName(iMth) & " " & YEAR
        If count(iMth) > 0 Then
            .Offset(1, iMth - 1) = sum(iMth) / count(iMth)
            .Offset(1, iMth - 1).NumberFormat = "0.0"
        End If
    Next
    End With

    Dim msg As String
    msg = iRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Table 2 updated"

End Sub
```

How can I in addition to the code above, count the number of the rows from the source workbook 1 if they fulfill the criteria below and enter the result to specific cells in workbok 2?

**The criteria should be as follows:**

If a row in **Workbbook 1** has the values in **Column H = "01.January"** and  **Column AD = < 50** then count and enter the result in (*green*)cell **B8 of Workbook 2** after the whole workbook 1 is checked.

If a row in **Workbbook 1** has the values **Column H = "01.January"** and  **Column AD = > 50 and < 100** then count and enter the result in (*yellow*)cell **B9 of Workbook 2** after the whole workbook 1 is checked.

If a row in **Workbbook 1** has the values **Column H = "01.January"** and  **Column AD = > 100** then count and enter the result in (*red*)cell **B10 of Workbook 2** after the whole workbook 1 is checked.

And the same thing for February, March, April etc.

**In summary: I want to know how many of the rows in workbook 1 are green,yellow or red based on the criteria I defined above. And this for every month.**

In the end it should look like this:

[image]

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: COUNTIFS .....?

Comment: Yes, but not sure how to convey it in VBA form?